# How to set multiple conditions for multiple values in a row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, bioinformatics

I have a genetic data set where each row describes a gene and has a beta column with multiple beta values I've compressed into one row/cell (from the variant level where multiple variants in one gene gave multiple betas). The beta is the effect size that the gene can have on a condition so large negative values are important as well as large positive values. I am trying to write code that selects either the largest negative or largest positive beta value for a gene, cutting off at -0.5 and 0.5.

The rules I am trying to code are these:

If a gene/row has a value less than -0.5 and no values higher than 0.5 then keep only the largest negative value.

If it has a value higher than 0.5 and no values less than -0.5 keep only the largest positive value.

If it has no values less than -0.5 or more than 0.5 keep the largest value.

If it has both values less than -0.5 and more than 0.5 keep the largest value.

For example my data looks like this:

```
Gene    Beta(s)
ACE     0.01, -0.6, 0.4
BRCA    0.7, -0.2, 0.2 
ZAP70   0.001, 0.02, -0.003
P53     0.8, -0.6, 0.001
```

Expected output (selecting largest negative or positive values depending on set conditions):

```
Gene    Beta(s)
ACE     -0.6  
BRCA     0.7
ZAP70    0.02
P53      0.8
```

I am from a biology background and new to R, so not sure how to code this. At the moment I am working with functions to select either the maximum or minimum beta values for a gene, but I don't know how to amend this with further conditions:

```
max2 = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x,na.rm = T)
getmax = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x)max2(as.numeric(x)) ) %>%
  unlist() 

min2 = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else min(x,na.rm = T)
getmin = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x)min2(as.numeric(x)) ) %>%
  unlist() 

test <- df %>%
  mutate_at(names(df)[2],getmax)
```

Any help in the right direction of how to set multiple conditional statements would be appreciated.

Example data:

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(Gene = c("ACE", "BRCA", "ZAP70", "P53"), `Beta(s)` = c("0.01, -0.6, 0.4", 
"0.7, -0.2, 0.2", "0.001, 0.02, -0.003", "0.8, -0.6, 0.001")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: So they are all grouped according to the min and max values (against -0.5 and +0.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution that should work fast and indepentant of the number of beta's provided.

```
library( data.table )
library( matrixStats ) 
#set df as data.table
setDT( df )
#split Beta(s) to columns (dynamically)
df[, paste0( "Beta", 
             1:length( tstrsplit( df$`Beta(s)`, "," ) ) ) := 
     lapply( tstrsplit( `Beta(s)`, "," ), as.numeric ) ][]
#     Gene             Beta(s) Beta1 Beta2  Beta3
# 1:   ACE     0.01, -0.6, 0.4 0.010 -0.60  0.400
# 2:  BRCA      0.7, -0.2, 0.2 0.700 -0.20  0.200
# 3: ZAP70 0.001, 0.02, -0.003 0.001  0.02 -0.003
# 4:   P53    0.8, -0.6, 0.001 0.800 -0.60  0.001


#now, using rowMINs ans RowMAxs from the matrixStats-package (=FAST!!)
# get the filtering (and updating) done by reference.

#If a gene/row has a value less than -0.5 and no values higher than 0.5 then keep only the largest negative value.
df[ df[, rowMins( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] < -0.5 &
      df[, rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] <= 0.5,
    Beta.final := rowMins( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ]
#If it has a value higher than 0.5 and no values less than -0.5 keep only the largest positive value.
df[ df[, rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] > 0.5 &
      df[, rowMins( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] >= -0.5,
    Beta.final := rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ]
#If it has no values less than -0.5 or more than 0.5 keep the largest value.
df[ df[, rowMins( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] >= -0.5 &
      df[, rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] <= 0.5,
    Beta.final := rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ]
#If it has both values less than -0.5 and more than 0.5 keep the largest value.
df[ df[, rowMins( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] < -0.5 &
      df[, rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ] > 0.5,
    Beta.final := rowMaxs( as.matrix(.SD), na.rm = TRUE ), .SDcols = patterns("^Beta[0-9]") ]
```

***output**

```
#final output
df[, .(Gene, `Beta(s)` = Beta.final )][]
#     Gene Beta(s)
# 1:   ACE   -0.60
# 2:  BRCA    0.70
# 3: ZAP70    0.02
# 4:   P53    0.80
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this looks like it will work well. I am just having an error ```Error: Pattern not found: [^Beta[0-9]]```. I have some genes with just NA as their beta, is this error due to this?  Is it that the [0-9] needs to account for this? I will try to get this to work in the meantime.

Comment: the regex `"^Beta[0-9]"` is looking for columns which name starts with `Beta`, followed by a number 0 - 9.  Check your colnames to see if any column matching this pattern exists..

Comment: Thank you, turns out I had some typos and this works now. It replaces NAs with -Inf  but I will try to switch them back to NA, everything else works as expected, thanks for your help.

Comment: correct... since `na.rm = TRUE` is set, it ignores out `NA`'s in determining max and/or min. See output of: `rowMaxs( matrix( c(1, NA, 3, 2, NA, NA), ncol = 2 ), na.rm = TRUE )`. But if you do not set `na.rm = TRUE`, output will not be as expected, see: `rowMaxs( matrix( c(1, NA, 3, 2, NA, NA), ncol = 2 ) )`. So replacing `-Inf` afterward is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Though the logic is not fully clear to me, most likely something like that:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  separate("Beta(s)", sep = ",", into = str_c("v", 1:3)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("v")), as.numeric) %>%
  mutate(vmax = pmax(v1, v2, v3), vmin = pmin(v1, v2, v3)) %>%
  mutate(want = case_when(vmax > 0.5 & vmin > -0.5 ~ vmax, # if vmax is > 0.5, it is always positive ..
                          abs(vmax) > abs(vmin) ~ vmax, # get largest absolute value ??
                          TRUE ~ vmin)) %>%
  select(Gene, want)


# Gene  want
# 1   ACE -0.60
# 2  BRCA  0.70
# 3 ZAP70  0.02
# 4   P53  0.80

## edited (handling multiple columns and NA):

df %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% 
              pull("Beta(s)") %>%
              str_split(",", simplify = TRUE) %>%
              `colnames<-`(str_c("v", 1:NCOL(.))) %>%
              as_tibble() %>%
              mutate_all(~str_remove_all(., "\\s") %>%
                           str_remove_all(., "NA") %>%
                           as.numeric) %>%
              mutate(vmax = pmap_dbl(., pmax, na.rm = T),
                     vmin = pmap_dbl(., pmin, na.rm = T))) %>%
  mutate(want = case_when(vmax > 0.5 & vmin > -0.5 ~ vmax, 
                          abs(vmax) > abs(vmin) ~ vmax, 
                          TRUE ~ vmin)) %>%
  select(Gene, want)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this has ran very efficiently. In my actual dataset I have more than 3 values in my rows or some with just NA -not sure if that matters, but is there a way to expand this to consider all values despite the amount of them per row?

Comment: Yes, but it's getting messy. :-)